# what is equivalent for hibernate X.hbm.xml filters equivalent in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm switching my spring mvc project to spring boot version. 
i use `filters` in my `hbm` files. 
For example :

```
<filter name="subsiteFilter" condition=" subsite_id=:subsiteId "  />
```

i get error :

```
Filter [subsiteFilter] parameter [subsiteId] value not set
```

is there any equivalent or configuration in spring boot?

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430187/filters-for-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use @FilterDefs, @Filter, @FilterJoinTable annotations.